# Movups instruction counter

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Hello I am looking for optimizations used by gcc. In the below code I copy long hard coded string using stpcpy. In the below assembly you can see bunch of movups instructions that copies content of xmm0 register into rbx register. What I dont understand is there is no change to xmm0 or relative addressing. Shouldn't this code just copy start of xmm register into different parts of rbx? Is there some kind of internal counter for movups instruction?

```
char* stpcpy_test2(char* str){
char *filler = "filler2waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawdawaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
char *ret = malloc(300);
stpcpy(str, filler);

strcpy(ret , "aahahaeheheheadwad");
return ret;}
```

And the resulting assembly on gcc 9.3 using -O3 option is below

```
stpcpy_test2:
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rdi
    mov     edi, 300
    call    malloc
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    movabs  rdx, 7016996765293437281
    movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbx+176], rdx
    mov     edx, 25697
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx], xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
    mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+184], 0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+16], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+32], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+64], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+80], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+96], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+112], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+128], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+144], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+160], xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
    mov     WORD PTR [rax+16], dx
    mov     BYTE PTR [rax+18], 0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+48], xmm1
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

Comment: This is copying your long string into the allocated buffer.  Since your string is very repetitive, many different places can be filled with the same bytes, so those bytes might as well stay in xmm0.  There's no need for a loop or any "counter"; the compiler knows how long the string is, and just generates the right number of instructions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Every `movups` store *is* using a separate memory, using different offset from RBX with `[rbx + displacement]` addressing modes.  (And of course it's not writing to the RBX register, it's writing to memory pointed to by RBX.)  Also, you realize your function has two unrelated copies, right?  One `strcpy` into the malloced buffer you return (`rax`), and one `stpcpy` into the incoming function arg (RDI, copied to RBX).

Comment: Single-step through this in a debugger with a `display (char [300])$rbx` or whatever the GDB syntax is to have it show you the changing memory contents.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes i know this is just a function i use for testing. From what i understand parts of xmm0 is just getting copied to address referenced by rbx. Nate Eldredge I will try with different characters in string you might be right about same repetitive characters

Comment: @DreadfulWeather: That's not quite right.  `movups` copies **all** of `xmm0` into the relevant memory location.  And the address of the location in question is the address in `rbx` **plus** a displacement that varies from line to line.  E.g. `movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+16], xmm0` and `movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbx+32], xmm0` copy the same 16 bytes  of data (presumably 16 bytes of `'a'`) into two different places (namely bytes 16-31 and 32-47 of the buffer which `rbx` points to).

Comment: @NateEldredge i tried it with varying string and you are absolutely right. Compiler is definitely smarter than I expected. Its for sure smarter than me

Comment: suggest reading: [movups instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movups) for all the details and variations of the 'movups' instruction